# (can't install package) ERROR: compilation failed for package 'fim4r' "arules"

Tags: r, arules

I'm trying to install a fim4r package without success.

a little about the package
[enter link description here](http://mhahsler.github.io/arules/)

mining algorithms including the code of Christian Borgelt’s popular and efficient C implementations of the association mining algorithms Apriori and Eclat. In addition, the following mining algorithms are available via fim4r:

```
library(arules)
arules::fim4r()


..
...
....
.......
-DQUIET -O3 -funroll-loops -Iutil/src -Imath/src  -Itract/src -Iapriori/src -Ieclat/src -Ifpgrowth/src -Isam/src  -Irelim/src -Icarpenter/src -Iista/src -Iaccretion/src -DISTA_ABORT ista/src/ista.c -o ista.o
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-unused-parameter -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -pedantic -c  -DNDEBUG -DQUIET -O3 -funroll-loops -Iutil/src -Imath/src  -Itract/src -Iapriori/src -Ieclat/src -Ifpgrowth/src -Isam/src  -Irelim/src -Icarpenter/src -Iista/src -Iaccretion/src -DISR_CLOMAX -DACC_ABORT \
              accretion/src/accretion.c -o accretion.o
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-unused-parameter -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -pedantic -c  -DNDEBUG -DQUIET -O3 -funroll-loops -Iutil/src -Imath/src  -Itract/src -Iapriori/src -Ieclat/src -Ifpgrowth/src -Isam/src  -Irelim/src -Icarpenter/src -Iista/src -Iaccretion/src -DFPG_ABORT fpgrowth/src/fpgpsp.c -o fpgpsp.o
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-unused-parameter -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -pedantic -c  -DNDEBUG -DQUIET -O3 -funroll-loops -Iutil/src -Imath/src  -Itract/src -Iapriori/src -Ieclat/src -Ifpgrowth/src -Isam/src  -Irelim/src -Icarpenter/src -Iista/src -Iaccretion/src -ID:/Program Files/R/R-43~1.0/include fim4r.c -o fim4r.o
fim4r.c:22:10: fatal error: R.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include "R.h"
      |          ^~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile.win:314: fim4r.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'fim4r'
* removing 'D:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/library/fim4r'
Available methods in fim4r are: ‘apriori’, ‘eclat’, ‘fpgrowth’, ‘carpenter’, ‘ista’, ‘relim’, ‘sam’Warning message:
In utils::install.packages(fim4r_url, repos = NULL) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/TARAS/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpuqdg3g/downloaded_packages/fim4r_latest.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

my session,
Rtools43 installed

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default


time zone: Asia/Damascus
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] arules_1.7-6 Matrix_1.5-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0  generics_0.1.3  tools_4.3.0     rstudioapi_0.14 grid_4.3.0      lattice_0.21-8 
>
```

Comment: You might be lacking `Rtools43` in order to compile from source. There's a description of what's needed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/howto-R-4.3.html) and you can find an executable that bundles everything together [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/files/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple ..
`R` must be installed on C drive.

Otherwise it won't work